# is it possible to view one html element twice on the same page, or must I create a duplicate?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a site that allows viewing and editing the contents of the 'src-div' contents within the 'edit-div.'   I am not editing the src-div directly, because its thumbnailed using css zoom property.

I have considered using knockout.js to bind both elements to an observable. Currently, I have implemented the feature with jquery .html() function: simply set edit-div innerhtml to src-div innerhtml on 'select', and reverse the process after changes are made to edit-div to update the src-div.

I am wondering if I really need 2 divs here, or if there is some way to actually view the same element twice on a page, and any changes made will automatically reflect in both 'views,' elimiating the need to copy innerhtml property back and forth between two elements.

essentially, this is like a mirror effect, without the flip.

the closest thing I found so far is:

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Reflections/Reflections.html

Any recommended practices for performing this task are appreciated.

Comment: Just like humans, DOM elements can only be at one place at any given time .. for two "you", you need a clone :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Almost) everything you see on a page has a counterpart in the DOM. Everything in the DOM gets exactly rendered one time (apart from pseudo-classes). And every node in the DOM can only have one parent (no exclusions).

Unfortunately you'll have to clone the specific node and add changes to both, as there is no copy & translate mechanism in the current CSS documentation.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using jquery you can use one div and "clone" it. You can read this for more information.
http://api.jquery.com/clone/

If you set the class of the div to the same thing, you can have changes propagated to both. Then you can apply .addClass to the second div to apply a "reflected" affect (if that's your final goal).

Comment: Also, with jQuery there could be both elements in the same jQuery object, e.g. `elements = $(elm1).append(elm2)`; then `elements.attr(..)` (etc.) would affect them both at once.